# PHP hide $_GET variables in URL for login

Tags: php

I am trying to create a link that logs a user into a website using $_GET variables but i dont want these variables to be seen in the URL or in any hidden fields in the source code of the website

What would be the best way to do this? I thought about using CURL in PHP but i wasnt sure if this would be able to redirect to the new page once logged in

Comment: You can put those variables in session.

Comment: Use form post method instead of get method. It is not a good practice to run login script by using get method.

Comment: could i not use CURL ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible, similar questions have been answered before and usually resolved by styling a form to look like a link.

The markup might be similar to this:

```
<form action="/do/stuff.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="123" />
    <button>Go to user 123</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Check out these other SO questions:
[How to pass POST parameters in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210900/how-to-pass-post-parameters-in-a-url)
[how to pass POST variable by links to own pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887080/how-to-past-post-variable-by-links-to-own-pages)
[cfhttp Passing POST variables via a link that is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841457/cfhttp-passing-post-variables-via-a-link-that-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

GET requests shouldn't be used for data you want hidden from the user/browser history.

Suggest using POST method form your form instead, and the user will not have visibility of the data.